# android studio how to add lib like the eclipse that use USER_LIBRARY

Tags: android-studio, dependencies

I have a question ,Hope everybody can help me to solve.

**Question:**

Use custom android.jar, not reference class, and can not be compiled, not like the eclipse that use org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY

This is the wording of eclipse:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <classpath>
 ...
 <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/user"/>
 ...
 </classpath>
```

**This is my test project:**  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5NNCuiWf6H2SHlBMmlUdjFQd28

Can not refer to lib / customization_classes.jar of public static String IOF_VERSION = android.os.Build.SW_VERSION;

**This is compiled error by gradle:**

D: \ AndroidStudioProjects \ Iof_workspace \ Iof \ testlib \ src \ main \ java \ com \ iof \ testlib 
\ MainActivity.java: 10: can not find symbol 
Symbol: variable SW_VERSION 
Location: Class android.os.Build 
     public static String IOF_VERSION = android.os.Build.SW_VERSION; 
                                                       ^ 
An error 
: testlib: compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: 
  Execution failed for task ': testlib: compileDebugJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try: 
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug 
  option to get more log output.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please, add more details and clear indications, where is error output and where you share your own thoughts.

Comment: thank,gradle Compile error is can not find symbol Symbol: variable SW_VERSION Location: Class android.os.Build   ,the SW_VERSION in lib / customization_classes.jar /android.os.Build

Answer (score 0):

guy,you can solve it like this:
In your module--->build.gradle add code:
dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/libs/xxx.jar')

}

That's OK!!! no Thanks